# Do I need to open the client(I use multiBit) while transaction is being confirmed?

Tags: transactions, multibit

Do I need to keep the client(I use multiBit) running while transaction is being confirmed? I have started a transaction at 1:00 nignight, when I get up at 6:00, it still didn't finish! they say a transaction need 6 confirm witch cost about 1,5 hours.

Comment: Are you sending or receiving?

Answer (score 3):

No need to keep the client open. Whatever client that is.
The confirmations take place in the bitcoin network, not locally.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep MultiBit running whilst a transaction confirms no as it will automatically sync with the network when it starts up.

How long a transaction takes to confirm is quite variable as it depends on how quickly blocks arrive, your fee and how busy the network is.

Comment: Now it's 16 hours past since I started transaction,seems the transaction stopped at 4-th block. when I withdraw from MTgox, I chosed add fee to speed up transaction. can't imagine it takes such long for just 4 BTC. are you sure there's no bug here?

Comment: not 4-th block, status icon is still empty, it has just "Seen by 4 peers" means it did'n even start confirm